# LINQ converting date, need to handle bad date

Tags: sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, date

I'm using LINQ-to-SQL and need to order by a date field.  The date field is stored as text and could have anything in it since it is user entered data.  I need to handle cases where an invalid date was placed in there.
For example, a date of "02/23/0000" returns:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

I need to avoid errors and I don't care where an invalid date like this gets sorted to.  The parameters of the project mean I can't modify my source data, only read from it.
Here is an example LINQ statement.

```
from x in dbo_myTable
orderby Convert.ToDateTime(x.MyDateField)
select x
```

Comment: And this is why you dont store dates in a varchar field!

Comment: I think the biggest problem is "the date field is stored as text and could have anything in it since it is user entered data"... why don't you use the correct data type and validate your input so people can't stuff garbage into your database? The easiest way to do do this is with any of a million free calendar controls out there. Barring that, you could filter your data using ISDATE() but that is like putting a band-aid on a shotgun wound.

Comment: There might be a workaround if there is some consistency with the data. Are all date strings 10 characters long?
Formatted like "DD/DD/DDDD"? D - Digit?

Comment: @Aaron - I addressed this below, this is historical data and there were no validations in place.

Comment: @Aducci - Yes, they are all 10 characters.  I'm not sure if there was a validation that it had to be numeric characters for the date.   In this case the problem was "0000" is not a valid year, so I'd take a solution that assumed numerical date with slashes.

Comment: @Jamice - Tell that to my company 20 years ago when they wrote their software! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this (Based on your comment that they are all 10 characters)

```
from x in dbo_myTable
orderby x.MyDateField.Substring(6, 4), x.MyDateField.Substring(0, 2), x.MyDateField.Substring(3, 2)
select x
```

Comment: As awkward a solution as this is. I think it's what I'll have to go with. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you *definitely* need to perform the ordering in the database? In this situation I would strongly consider pulling all of the data, then performing some conversion in .NET code where you have a great deal more control over what's going on, and then order it still in .NET code.

Ultimately, dealing with screwed up data in this sort of situation is tricky - the more control you have, the better.

Comment: Yes, it has to be here.  I'm using an environment where I can only specify the LINQ query and the software takes that and populates tables on another server.

Comment: If you're ultimately populating tables, then why does order matter? You know that the order of the select query is not guaranteed to end up being identical to the order that the data is stored in the destination table, right?

Comment: It's kind of complex.  I'm running the same LINQ query twice so I can populate two separate tables, but there is also a function run on one of the fields to handle duplicates on a field that doesn't allow duplicates, so I need it in order so both tables get the same values for that field.  Also, it goes in to the table and gets a new ID, so I want it to be in the order it was entered originally (and that means sorting by a date field)

Comment: @VenerableAgents: I would push back as hard as you can on the requirement to not fix the data. Ultimately, garbage data will keep screwing you over until you get it sorted. It's going to be even harder when you have all these other constraints.

Comment: @Jon Agreed, but I'm stuck with what I've got.  I deal with bad data all day long, it's part of my job really.  This bad data gets moved to a system that doesn't allow bad data :)

Answer (score 0):

First is first; *why* cant you change the database to fix you obviously brokes table structure? Why cant you sanitize input when its going into the database? Why are you not validating user input?

Now for the answer; your only option is attempt to parse the date (with DateTime.TryParse or DateTime.TryParseExact) and set a default value of your choosing if it fails to parse:

```
from x in dbo_myTable
orderby TryConvertToDateTime(x.MyDateField)
select x

private DateTime TryConvertToDateTime(string dt)
{
   DateTime rtn = DateTime.MinValue; // or whatever you want your default to be
   DateTime.TryParse(dt,out rtn);
   return rtn;
}
```

Comment: In answer to WHY: This is historical data and there just happens to have not been any validation on the user input at that time.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I was going to say, that doesn't work for me.  I need a pure LINQ solution.

Comment: My bad, I thought this was LINQ to objects. Note to self: Tags are there for a reason.